# I'm having trouble understanding SPST terminology

Tags: switches, terminology

Before someone LMGTFYs me, let me get this straight: I HAVE DUCKDUCKGO'ed this already, but I still cannot understand what switch 'pole' and 'throw' mean. I really just need a clearer explanation of switch terminology please!

Comment: Think of "Pole" as a piece of wire. "Throw" as the number of "outputs" you can connect it to. So, n Pole (n wires), m Throw, each wire you can connect to other m "outputs".

Comment: so how would a double pole switch work? can each pole be connected to any "output" at any time?

Comment: I'm writing an answer with some images. Just a sec.

Comment: Double pole switches are ganged, all the poles switch at once, if they did not there would logically be two switches.  The go-to example generally involves a wooden chair. When I had to work this out I used (counted) the terminals on the base of the switch.  Simple relays are similar.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Think of "Poles" as a piece of wire you want to connect somewhere.
And "Throws" as places where you can connect that wire to.

*N* Poles = *N* wires

*M* Throws = *M* places where you can connect each of the N wires to.

**SPST**

(Note that on a SPST there isn't necessarily a side which is the Pole or the Throw.)

The following might help you understand the terminology better:

- To add a "Throw" you just add an extra connection on the right side. (therefore one pin at least, becoming SPDT)
- To add a "Pole" you duplicate the entire thing, therefore at least 2 pins, becoming DPST.

[image]

**SPDT**

Following is a SPDT. Which means you have a piece of wire you can connect to two places.

- To add a "Throw", you just need to add a new place to connect it to (one more pin on the right side, having a SP3T).
- To add a "Pole", you would have to add a piece of wire and two places to connect it to, therefore at least 3 pins and duplicating the entire thing. (Assuming you are maintaining it as Double Throw)

[image]

Images are from [Sparkfuns](https://learn.sparkfun.com/tutorials/switch-basics/poles-and-throws-open-and-closed) explanation.

Comment: @parzival - note that not all double poles have double throws, etc. Is that clear on the answer? You can have Double Pole Single Throw, which is just two times the first image.

Answer (score 2):

According to [SPST, SPDT, DPST, and DPDT Explained](http://www.littelfuse.com/technical-resources/technical-centers/commercial-vehicle-technical-center/poles-and-throws.aspx) by littelfuse:

> SP: Single Pole, one circuit controlled by the switch.
>
> DP: Double Pole two independent circuits controlled by the switch
>   which are mechanically linked.
>
> Note: “Pole” should not be confused with “Terminal”. The DPST switch,
>   for example has four terminals however is a Double Pole (DP) and not a
>   four pole (4P) switch.
>
> ST: Single Throw, closes a circuit at only one position. The center
>   position is off.
>
> DT: Double Throw, closes a circuit in the up or down position (On-On).
>   A Double Throw switch can also have a center position such as
>   On-Off-On.

When comparing SPST vs SPDT - both have the 2 states. In case of SPST they are On/OFF, but in case of SPDT they can be ON1/ON2, so you can use SPDT as SPST when you would leave the 3rd pin unconnected.

Same naming convention is used for relays, see below diagram:

NO - means "normally open"

NC - means "normally connected"

[image: contacts configurations]

<sub>([Original image source](https://www.tme.eu/u/parameters_info/contacts_configuration.gif) and [example web page using that image](https://www.tme.eu/en/katalog/rocker-switches_100054/) - see "i" icon near "Contacts configuration" option list)</sub>

Answer (score 1):

The number of poles is the number of wires that can be switched simultaneously. In other words, a double-pole switch is basically just two switches sitting next to each other, with a single button or lever (or whatever) to activate both simultaneously.

A single throw switch means the output is simply either connected or not connected to the input.

A double throw switch means there are two inputs and one output (or vice versa). In one switch position, the output is connected to one input. In the other switch position, the output is connected to the other input.

To give a simple example of how this is used, consider a typical "two way" switch for a light. The schematic looks like this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fHFuJn.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

so, it both switches are in the "up" position, we get power at the output. Likewise, if both switches are in the "down" position, power is transmitted. But, if one is down and the other is up, there's no connection through, so no power at the output. If the circuit is on, switching either switch will turn it off. If it's off, changing either switch will turn it on.